# ¿Como cambiar el valor de una variable static?

Tags: java

Buenas, me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar el valor de la siguiente constante (Por poner un ejemplo) mediante un método.

```
private static double PIVA=0.16;
```

Edito: Me he expreado mal, lo siento. Usé mal la palabra "constante", quería referirme a esa variable "static". Está definida al principio de la clase.

Gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: @B.ClayShannon en Java la palabra `const` no tiene ningún efecto. Creo que en C# sí lo tiene.

Comment: @Akarin Tengo entendido en programación general una constante, no tiene sentido cambiar su valor. En Java para definir una constante debes usar final.

Comment: @Webserveis claro que se puede cambiar su valor, así sea privado.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza pero si está definida cómo constante, java te deja cambiar su valor sin que salte una excepción?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: ay caramba; en esto caso, perdoname. Aun tiene Webserveis razon: no tiene sentido cambiar el valor de un "const"

Comment: @Webserveis mira mi respuesta al respecto :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si ahora estoy leyendo eso de la reflexión, veo que Java es todo un mundo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tienes allí no es una constante, solo es una variable estática. Para que sea una constante, debe estar definido con el modificador `final`:

```
private static final double PIVA=0.16;
```

Al ser una constante, su valor **no se puede cambiar**.

---

Imagina que el campo se encuentra en una clase con la siguiente definición (manteniendo tal cual lo declaras en tu ejemplo).

```
class ClaseConCampoEstatico {
    private static double PIVA = 0.16;
    public static final double getPIVA() { return PIVA; }
}
```

Si quieres cambiar su valor, puedes hacerlo vía reflexión. Se necesita conocer el nombre del campo que se quiere modificar y luego lo demás sería simple uso de reflexión, así:

```
//obtenemos el campo que queremos modificar
//el método getDeclaredField busca en todos los campos de la clase
//sin importar su visibilidad (private, default, protected, public)
Field field = ClaseConCampoEstatico.class.getDeclaredField("PIVA");
//se define que el campo es accesible
field.setAccessible(true);
//se cambia el valor del campo
//el primer parámetro consiste del objeto sobre el cual
//se va a cambiar el valor del campo
//como se trata de un campo estático, el valor no depende de
//una variable en particular por lo que solo usamos null
//el segundo parámetro consiste del nuevo valor que tendrá el campo
field.setDouble(null, <nuevo valor>);
```

Crearemos un método para realizar el ejemplo:

```
class ClaseConCampoEstatico {
    private static double PIVA = 0.16;
    public static double getPIVA() { return PIVA; }
}

public class Main {
    public static void cambiaValor(double nuevoValor) {
        try {
            Field field = ClaseConCampoEstatico.class.getDeclaredField("PIVA");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.setDouble(null, nuevoValor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo cambiar el valor :(");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ClaseConCampoEstatico.getPIVA());
        cambiaValor(1.0);
        System.out.println(ClaseConCampoEstatico.getPIVA());
    }
}
```

La salida del programa:

```
0.16
1.0
```

Sin embargo, si fuese una **verdadera constante**, es decir, que el campo esté marcado como `final`, veríamos una excepción:

```
class ClaseConCampoEstatico {
    private static final double PIVA = 0.16;
    public static double getPIVA() { return PIVA; }
}
//resto del código...
```

La salida será:

```
0.16
No se pudo cambiar el valor :(
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final double field ClaseConCampoEstatico.PIVA to (double)1.0
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticDoubleFieldAccessorImpl.setDouble(UnsafeQualifiedStaticDoubleFieldAccessorImpl.java:159)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.setDouble(Field.java:1060)
        at Main.cambiaValor(Main.java:13)
        at Main.main(Main.java:22)
0.16
```

Ahora, ten en cuenta que `Field#setAccessible` no siempre funcionará. Esto es debido a que en algunos entornos de ejecución, existe un [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) que provee seguridad a la aplicación. Como parte de la seguridad, evita que los campos puedan ser modificados por reflexión para evitar ataques. Esto sucede por ejemplo al ejecutar un Applet.

Comment: Gracis por la respueta, me confundí de terminos, he editado el mensaje principal!

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta antes que se cambiase el titular. `¿Cómo cambiar el valor de una constante?`

En `java` para definir una constante se usa `final`

```
private static final double PIVA=0.16;
```

Y si lo defines cómo una constante, no tiene sentido en poder cambiar su valor dinámicamente.

Comment: Pues, perfectamente es posible que una variable estática que en un principio era constante requiera cambiar su valor, por lo tanto no es necesario tener que usar estrictamente `final`. Si nos ponemos mas estrictos, las constantes deben ser "seteadas" mediante archivos .properties

Comment: Bueno antes de cambiase el titular era: como cambiar el valor de una constante.